# Sum of two decreasing function

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are decreasing function. Can we conclude that $f(x) + g(x)$ is also decreasing ? In general can we deduct that sum of monotonic functions is also monotonic and if functions are increasing or decreasing then sum of them is also increasing or decreasing ? If these statements are true , how we can prove it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Assume $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are decreasing in $[a,b]$ and **were defined** in this interval. For every $s$ and $t$ that $a\leq s\leq t\leq b$ we have
$$f(s)\geq f(t)\hspace{1cm};\hspace{1cm}g(s)\geq g(t)$$
so
$$f(s)+g(s)\geq f(t)+g(t)$$

Comment: So sum of several increasing functions is increasing and sum of several decreasing functions is decreasing . Is it right ?

Comment: They must be define in same set.

Comment: Yes they are defined in same interval

Comment: @Nosrati you used the definition of increasing function by mistake.